# Algorithm: how to find a column in matrix filled with all 1, time complexity O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix which looks like this:

```
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
```

I should find if this matrix has a column filled with all 1. At this matrix it's column 4. And it's said that time complexity is O(n) and memory is O(1).

This matrix represents a binary relation on a set (of people). `n` is the size of the set, so the size of the matrix is `n * n`.

I can see 2 possible solutions:

- Take the first column, go through it, if see zero, jump on the next column and so on. But the worst case of this algorithm will be O(n<sup>2</sup>);
- The next one, if I will have a sum of all columns than I can give an answer in O(n). But it's not said at task conditions that we have computed sums. And if I will compute them, the complexity will be also O(n<sup>2</sup>);

Any other solutions?

Comment: Is `n` the number of elements in the matrix or its dimensions?

Comment: You need to parellelize your algorithm to process one column using one thread or process. That's how Matrix Image Processing in Cameras are done.

Comment: @shazin That doesn't change the algorithm complexity.

Comment: @shazin: Parallelization doesn't change the time complexity.

Comment: You could also improve the worst case in the face of malicious input by checking for zeroes in random rows of a given column but that still only gets you to a "better" O(n2), and assumes generating random permutations costs nothing. (Which, in practice, it doesn't.)

Comment: The question doesn't make sense unless you define `n` - if it is the number of elements in the matrix, then O(n), if it's the dimension of a square matrix then O(n^2).

Comment: @RogerRowland: I think we can infer that `n` is the dimension here...

Comment: O(n) for which abstract machine? For the most commonly known one, the turing machine, there's no O(n) algorithm without assumptions (justification: you'd have to check the whole column to see if it's all ones, and you might have to do that check for all columns). Other models may allow one, for example PRAM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me take a very wild guess on what you are trying to do. Hint from the mention of:

1. The array represent relation on people
2. You are finding a column with all 1s
3. You are trying to find an `O(n)` algorithm

Well, you can not do that in `O(n)` and I can prove that it is `O(n^2)` only.

But my **wild** guess is that you doing a classic **[celebrity identification problem](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos423/problem0-1.pdf)**, and that you **misunderstood** the problem.

> A celebrity is person that is known by every other person, but doesn't
>   know any [other people].

I celebrity identification problem, you are trying to find something like:

```
Find the number i where
a[i][x] = 1 for all x            -> every one knows the celebrity
a[x][i] = 0 for all x != i       -> the celebrity doesn't know anyone else
```

And indeed with this extra constrain on what you are trying to find, there is an `O(n)` solution.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought too.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming arbitrary content, you cannot avoid a worst-case of O(n<sup>2</sup>).<sup>*</sup>  You have to visit every element in each column that you want to consider, and in the worst-case, you have to consider all columns.

---

<sub>* Also assuming that `n` is the matrix dimension here, not the total number of elements.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't* assume arbitrary content (as in Oli's answer) and you can encode each row as an unsigned integer with binary flags, then you *can* do it in O(n) and O(1) by just repeatedely performing a logical `AND` of each row with the latest result.

The final set of flags will only have ones where the relevant column was also one.

Comment: This assumes that operations on a word of arbitrary size can be done in constant time...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - yes, that's right it does - it may be of general interest though as a potential implementation help.

Comment: It's not as wrong as people seem to think, treating elementary operations on arbitrary-length words as O(1) is a valid and used model (if perhaps not overly realistic, but then, almost none of them are, they're all abstractions that fail if you push them too far). But that you're doing that should really be noted.. Also it doesn't give the *index* of the column, but that would only take O(log n) further steps.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more details? Cause I don't understand how to implement it :(

Answer (score 0):

What is the input for the matrix?

If you get a number for each column, i.e. in your example (in decimal) 14, 8, 4, 31, 1, you could just create a number `a` with `n` binary digits set to 1 (in this case 31). If this number is equal to one of the column numbers, one of the columns is all 1s.

Comment: And what if the size of the matrix is bigger than your native data-types?

Comment: Then you have an `O(n^2)` problem. But if his teacher or whoever said there's an `O(n)` solution, there's something missing in the description of the task. If OP listed all information, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is that we first assume that all columns have 1s, then we go row by row, over the possible solutions we still have, and cut columns that cannot be a solution.

This solution is written in Java:

**Solution 1: O(n^2) straight-forward**

```
public class Main
{
    // Given A: an M x N matrix
    public static ArrayList<Integer> solve (Integer [][] matrix)
    {
        // Assuming all columns have 1s, we have list S
        ArrayList<Integer> S = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // S = { 1, 2, .., N }
        for (int i=0; i < matrix[0].length; i++)
        {
            S.add(i);
        }

        // For Row i: 1..M
        for (Integer i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
        {
            // For Column j in list S
            for (Integer j : S)
            {
                if (matrix[i][j] != 1)
                {
                    S.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }

        return S;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int [][] matrix =
        {
            {1,1,1},
            {0,1,1},
            {0,0,1},
        };

        ArrayList<Integer> columns = solve (matrix);

        System.out.print(" columns that have 1s are: ");

        for (Integer n : columns) System.out.print(n+" ");
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: O(n) using a customized data-structure**

```
private class Column
{
    public ArrayList<Integer> data;
    public int count;

    public Column ()
    {
        data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        count = 0;
    }

    public void add (int val)
    {
        data.add(val);
        count += val;
    }
}

public class Main
{

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Column [] matrix =
        {
            new Column (),
            new Column (),
            new Column ()
        };

        matrix[0].add(1);
        matrix[0].add(0);
        matrix[0].add(0);

        matrix[1].add(1);
        matrix[1].add(1);
        matrix[1].add(0);

        matrix[2].add(1);
        matrix[2].add(1);
        matrix[2].add(1);

        System.out.print(" columns that have 1s are: ");

        for (Column column : matrix)
        {
             if (column.count == column.data.size())
                 System.out.print(n+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth check the second solution I added, it's O(n)

Comment: Sure, if you can do preprocessing, then you can shift the complexity cost to the initialization.