# Writing an efficent method

Tags: algorithm, optimization, matrix

I was instructed to write a method for finding a "**cross**" in a square matrix (all the matrices in this question consist of 1s and 0s).

k is a **cross** if in the kth row all the elements are zero 0s and in the kth column all the elements are ones (except for the one in [k][k] which equals 0)

for example, 2 is a cross in this matrix: 
1 0 1 
0 1 1 
0 0 0

I need to write an efficent method which returns k if there is a cross in the matrix and -1 if there isn't one.

I was thinking about writing a method in the following design:

A loop that goes through all the numbers in the matrix's diagonal, checking for 0s.
if a 0 is found, i check for the sum of all the numbers in the row and see if it equals 0.
if it does, I check if for the sum of all the numbers in the column and check if it equals the matrix's length.

if it does, k is returned. if not, -1 is returned.
I am not sure what is the level of complexity of my solution though. if this is O(n^2) I don't get all the points. I'd be glad if someone could tell me if what I am suggesting is efficent enough (and what is the efficent level of it).

Help would be greatly appriciated. :)

Comment: Any particular programming language? Does the Matrix data type need to be 2-dimensional?

Comment: If your main diagonal is all zeros, which it might be, then you will have to read every cell as part of calculating every column total and every row total. That is clearly O(n^2) where your matrix is n*n.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771069

Answer (score 2):

It might be a little late by now, but the edit attracted my attention.

The problem reminds me of the celebrity problem. We can observe that there may be at most one cross. So, we can start the following procedure:

1. Initialize a stack with cross candidates (the initial stack is the sequence from 1 to column count (or 0 to column count - 1). Before any examination, all of these numbers may be the cross)
2. Iterate as long as there are two elements in the stack

   1. Pick the two topmost elements from the stack, let's call them `i` and `j`
   2. Examine the entry in the `i`-th row and `j`-th column. If the entry is 0, `j` can't be the cross (because the `j`-th column must only contain 1s). If the entry is 1, `i` can't be the cross
   3. Put the one candidate back on the stack that still can be the cross
3. Now we have only one candidate and need to check if it's really the cross (by examining its row and column).

The overall time complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: What are `cross candidates`? How is a stack "initialized" with them?

Comment: As stated in the answer: The stack is initialized with the sequence from 1 to column count. For 4 columns, the initial stack is `1, 2, 3, 4`. Each of these numbers may be the cross before any examination.

Answer (score 0):

Complexity seems O(n^2). All different combinations of matrix values in getMatrix() method are returning correct values.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = getMatrix();
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int columns = matrix[0].length;
    int choiceRow=-1; 

    //Parse matrix row by row.
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {           
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
        {
            //on the first column
            if(j==0 && matrix[i][0] == 0)
            {
                //there is a chance this can be the choiceRow
                choiceRow=i;
            }
            else if(j==0 && matrix[i][j] == 1)
            {
                //if first column in current row is 1, no need to traverse row
                break;
            }
            //If current column is not first column, and current row is selected as
            //choiceRow, and current element is not 0, then reset choiceRow
            else if(j>0 && matrix[i][j] != 0 && choiceRow ==i)
            {
                //reset choiceRow, because this cannot be the choiceRow as it has an 
                //entry that is 1
                choiceRow = -1;
                //No point traversing further
                break;
            }
            //Else traverse further, no change in choiceRow required if all other 
            //columns in current row are 0.
        }
        ///If current row is truly choiceRow, then check for values in current column 
        //if they're all 1 except at matrix[i][k]
        if(choiceRow ==i)
        {
            //Iterate over choiceRow column             
            for(int k=0;k<rows;k++)
            {
                //If current row == current column, then skip comparison
                if(k==choiceRow)
                    continue;
                //If current row in selected column has a non-1 value, then reset 
                //choiceRow to -1
                if(matrix[k][choiceRow] != 1)
                {                           
                    choiceRow = -1;
                }
            }

            //If choiceRow == i , ie, it is not -1, then stop iterating 
            //and return choiceRow to o/p 
            if(choiceRow !=-1)
                break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("ChoiceRow = "+choiceRow);
}

public static int[][] getMatrix()
{
//  int[][] matrix = {{1,0,1},{0,1,1},{0,0,0}};
//  int[][] matrix = {{1,0,1,0}, {1,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,0}, {1,0,1,1}};
//  int[][] matrix = {{1,0,1,1}, {1,0,0,1}, {1,0,1,1}, {0,0,0,1}};
    int[][] matrix = {{1,0,1,1}, {1,0,0,1}, {1,0,1,1}, {0,0,0,0}};      
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: yes, good point :). Thats the first solution that came to mind.

Comment: as a better approach to get choiceRow (in above) I could get choiceRow only by looking at rows which have 0 in diagonal position, but that wouldn't improve the complexity in worst case...