# O(n) algorithm to find a “publisher” in a social network

Tags: algorithm

I was asked a question how to find a "publisher" in a social network. Suppose the (simplified) social network only has "following" relationship between two users and one cannot follow himself. Then we define a "publisher" as a user who is followed by ALL other users but does not follow anyone.

More specifically, given such a social network graph in the format of adjacency matrix, say NxN bool matrix, where cell[i,j] indicates whether or not user i follows user j. How to find out the publisher.

What I can see is that there is at most one publisher could exist.(it's easy to prove: since publisher is followed by everyone else, then everyone else follows at least one user, so they are not publisher). I do come up with a naive solution: first scan column by column, if there is a all true column j (except for cell[j,j] of course), then scan row[j] to make sure it's all false.

Obviously, the performance is O(n^2) for the naive algorithm cause we scan the whole matrix. However, I was told that there is an O(n) solution. I am kind of stuck at O(n). Any hints?

Comment: Social networks are usually very sparsed graphs. A nxn matrix implementation is a bad choice for those kind of graphs.

Comment: Are you sure that the O(n) algorithm operates on an adjacency matrix? With adjacency lists, it's easy. With the matrix, I don't think it's possible, as there are n^2 data points and there doesn't appear to be any shortcut by which one can rule out most of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771069/algorithm-how-to-find-a-column-in-matrix-filled-with-all-1-time-complexity-on Just the celebrity problem.

Comment: @Ali In this post it looks like there is at least some effort reasoning about the problem (noting there is only one publisher) and an O(n^2) time algorithm is mentioned by the OP, whose expected running time is faster than O(n^2) for random sparse matrices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your data is presented as an adjacency matrix, then you can proceed as follows. Start by checking entry (1,2) in the matrix. If 1 follows 2 then 1 is not the publisher, and if 1 does not follow 2 then 2 is not the publisher. Remove whoever is not the publisher (1 or 2) and let X be the remaining node. Then check entry (X,3) in the matrix. Similarly you will get that either X is not the publisher or 3 is not the publisher. Remove whoever is not the publisher and then add node 4 and repeat. After you have repeated this process with all n nodes, you will be left with one candidate for the publisher. Then you can check the row and column for the candidate to verify that it is a true publisher. Total running time is O(n) for the entire algorithm, even though the adjacency matrix has size n^2.

Comment: You missed this part - If both 1 and 2 follow each other, remove both (and then check (3,4)).

Comment: @Dukeling that observation would potentially give a small speed-up but it doesn't change the O(n) running time.  We just need to eliminate one candidate each time we test a pair.