# Determining if Adjacency Matrix has certain Vertex

Tags: algorithm, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that has to run in O(n) time and that determines if an adjacency matrix has a vertex that has 0 edges leaving (ie, the row of this vertex in the adjacency matrix is all false) and has all edges other than itself coming in (ie, the column in the adjacency matrix is all true but for the place that the aforementioned false row crosses). Any ideas on such an algorithm?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484373/on-algorithm-to-find-a-publisher-in-a-social-network/21485033#21485033

Answer (score 0):

This question appeared in terms of a social network question to find a "publisher" in a social network adjacency matrix which looks like exactly the vertex you are looking for in your adjacency matrix. See [O(n) algorithm to find a “publisher” in a social network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484373/on-algorithm-to-find-a-publisher-in-a-social-network/21485033#21485033)